# How to calculate duration of hours, minute and second in a single row in excel?

Tags: excel-formula

How can I calculate only the string (word) **duration** of hours, minute, and second in a separate column?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMqic.jpg)

Comment: You could use MID because the number of characters before the time string appears to be fixed in your screenshot. `MID(A1,56,FIND(",",A1,56)-56)` for example would take the substring starting at character 56 and then look for the next comma and calculate how many characters to take. This FIND would protect you just in case the time string has double digit hours.

Answer (score 1):

Lets say that with data in column **A**, in **B1** we want to extract:

```
Duration: 0h:15m:11s
```

In **B1** enter:

```
=LEFT(MID(A1,FIND("Dur",A1),999),FIND(",",MID(A1,FIND("Dur",A1),999))-1)
```

and copy downwards.  We are looking for a substring beginning with `Dur` and ends just before the comma.

[image]

Comment: Now how can I find the total of hours, minutes,s, and seconds of below duration?
Duration: 0h:04m:58s
Duration: 0h:04m:58s
Duration: 0h:04m:59s